# How to create a static NSRange?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

It is really a stupid question, but I really don't know how to. 
I have a utility class and need to define some pre-defined variables. Here's how my class looks.

```
#pragma mark File header part definiation (start offset, length)
NSRange HEADER_VERSION = NSMakeRange(0, 4); /* 0,4 */
NSRange HEADER_IDENTIFIER = NSMakeRange(4, 18); /* 4, 18*/ 
...

@interface ParserUtil : NSObject {

}

/*Parse Paper instance from file*/
+(Paper*) parsePaper:(NSURL*)file;
@end
```

The compiler tell me the second and the third lines are error:

> initializer is not constant.

What is the best practice of defining the variables?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

NSRange is a plain c-struct so it can be initialized the following way:

```
NSRange HEADER_VERSION = {0, 4};
```

or

```
NSRange HEADER_VERSION = {.location = 0, .length = 4};
```

See [Designated inits](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.1/gcc/Designated-Inits.html#Designated-Inits) section of gcc manual for more details

Comment: Incidentally, icespace, none of these is static. To declare a static variable, you must put `static` in front of it.

Comment: Is the latter style supported under LLVM?

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about the `.location=` style of initialization